# How to write a SQL SELECT query to find content in one table that is missing link to the other?

Tags: mysql, sql

Two table employee and department each table has id and name column. Assume there are numerous content with both field populated and department id reference in each employee table record.
Question is How to find all the department names with no related employees in them?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic SQL query, which would commonly use `not in`, `not exists`, or `left join`.

Comment: Please share your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT department.id, department.name
FROM department
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee ON employee.department_id = department.id
WHERE employee.id IS NULL;
```

The left join means that this select will include every department row; where there are no employees for a given department, the employee columns will be null. We can then filter these results to *only* contain the rows where the employee columns are null.